# LAYERS param doesn't work with openlayers3 TileArcGISRest

Tags: openlayers

Using https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.source.TileArcGISRest.html

After creating a map source using [TileArcGISRest](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.source.TileArcGISRest.html) the params are not passed to the Arcgis Rest server.

```
  const source = new ol.source.TileArcGISRest({
      url: 'https://gisservices.information.qld.gov.au/arcgis/rest/services/PlanningCadastre/LandParcelPropertyFramework/MapServer',
      params: {
            'LAYERS':"show:2,4"
        },
      });

  }
  const layer =  new ol.layer.Tile({
      extent: [15238742.701475, -3469504.213328, 17340271.619744, -1022026.482164],
      source: source
    });
```

All the layers are displayed, not just the selected layers.
Looking at the URL sent by the browser, "&LAYERS="
Expected to see "&LAYERS=2,4".

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that ArcGISRest server has a different syntax to WMS servers.

```
      params: {
            'LAYERS':"show:2,4"
        },
      });
```

Has the desired result.

To be fair to openlayers, the TileArcGISRest API documens does refer to 
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#/Export_Map/02r3000000v7000000/

But it was not obvious and I could not find examples that select layers from an ArcGISRest source.